# ruby how to have two optional arguments but need at least one present?

Tags: ruby

I have this method, #upload, that basically takes in, amongst other arguments, a file option or some text. If a file (File.open("test.txt",'r+')) is passed,upload(:file => ...) , then this method reads from the file for the text, or if someone decides to pass that very same text just not in a txt file, he can do upload(:content => ...)

But I need either a file with the text or the text itself passed, how would you approach this?

Here's what I have so far.

```
 def upload(args)
   if args[:content].present?
     self.content = args[:content]
   elsif args[:file].present?
     self.content = args[:file].read
   end
 end
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what is your problem with the example code? How exactly is it not working for you?

Comment: I just wanted to know if this is the best approach. It does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

If the class of the argument is different (`String` vs. `File`), then you can use that in `case` construction. You do not need further information to distinguish that.

```
def upload(arg)
  self.content =
  case arg
  when String; arg
  when File; arg.read
  end
end
```

**Solution 2**

*Added after inspired by a comment by Nemo157*

Using polymorphism of object oriented programming, you can do this:

```
def upload(arg); self.content = arg.upload end
class String
  def upload; self end
end
class File
  def upload; read end
end
```

**Some notes on polymorphism**

Often, we refer to similar but different actions under the same word. For example, consider the word `add` in the context of ordinary life: we use it in different meanings: add water to the jar, add 3 to 1, add a comment, add shade of blue to the green paint, and so on. They have different meanings but we have the intuition that they are somehow related. One way to distinguish these meanings will be to use different words, like liquid-add, number-add, context-add, or may be you can number them like add1, add2, add3, but this is a mess. However, notice that their meaning depend largely on the type of the object it is predicated of: depending on whether it's liquid, number, discourse, etc., the appropriate sense of "add" while be determined. The idea of polymorphism uses this fact, and applies it to programming. In the case here, "upload" will have different meaning depending on whether its about a string or a file. But as long as they are defined within their respective class, you don't have to care about the difference when you use them. Hence, you are freed from case statement, and makes the code simpler.

Comment: You should (almost) never use class to switch on, it completely ruins duck-typing.  A better version of this would be first checking for the `to_str` method to tell if it's some form of string, then checking for `read` for if it's some sort of IO.

Comment: @Nemo157 Inspired after your comment, I added another solution to utilize polymorphism. I'm not sure if this is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks Sawa for offering two solutions, would you be kind enough to throw in a line or two as to why this is a good practice? I am still relatively new to programming in general. I immediately went to read Wikipedia's article on polymorphism of OO but couldn't get very far. Or perhaps you have some suggestion of some other articles I can check out. More of the type for noobs? Thank you.

Comment: @Nik I added a brief note on my understanding of polymorphism in object oriented programming.

Comment: THANK YOU! I think I got a better understanding of it now.

Comment: @sawa: I've added an example of what I meant to my answer.  I like the note on polymorphism, one of the simplest explanations I've seen :).

Answer (score 2):

Do you specifically want to pass the argument as a hash? If not I would go for something like:

```
def upload(args)
  if args.respond_to? :read
    self.content = args.read
  else
    self.content = args.to_s # This allows non-string arguments.
  end
end
```

Comment: I do like to pass the arguments in a hash, still relatively new to programming, but I find that more organized if more than 2 arguments are passed to a method, for I can see what is passed to the method acting as what, e.g., :content => "Hello". But definitely, your solution works

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a test in the method, something like

```
def upload(args)
  if args[:content].present?
    self.content = args[:content]
  elsif args[:file].present?
    self.content = args[:file].read
  else
    raise ArgumentError, 'one of :content or :file must be given'
  end
end
```

EDIT: alternative that uses just a single argument and duck-typing

```
def upload(arg)
  if arg.respond_to? :to_str
    self.content = arg.to_str
  elsif arg.respond_to? :read
    self.content = arg.read
  else
    raise ArgumentError, 'a String-like or IO-like object must be given'
  end
end
```

Similar to the other two but with what I feel are a couple of improvements

- Duck-typing instead of basing behaviour on the class, this means other classes could be used as long as they implement the right methods.  Mainly this allows other forms of IO other than just normal files.  Could be done with sub-typing, but that's not as much of a requirement in Ruby.
- Using `to_str` instead of `to_s`, every class has a `to_s` method and I'm assuming that you're not wanting to upload content like `#<MyClass:0x523e>`.  `to_str` on the other hand is only implemented by classes that specifically should be convertible to a string.

Comment: So my approach is generally accepted as a solution as well, right? That's basically I am looking to konw.

Comment: Your approach is fine, Ruby's a nice enough language that as long as it's readable it's good enough.  The main advantage consolidating it to a single argument has is that it reduces cognitive load, users of the method don't have to remember whether they should be writing `upload(content: my_string)` or `upload(file: my_file)` (using the new 1.9.2 hash syntax).  I've added how I would probably do it with a single argument and my reasoning.